# how to string manipulate and parse a url

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-comparison

say i have a list of random urls , the urls are fully formated:

```
http://www.example1.com, 
http://example2.biz, 
http://www.example3.co.uk
```

and i have My url value from a text box and a dropDownList for the urlSufix

so user is inserting a url:

label: `www.`  ,  textBox `[insert the domainNameOnly]` , DDL`[.com, .biz, .co.uk, .net, .info]`

and say user typed "example3" and chose sufix ".biz"

so my value is `"example3.biz"`

i need a method to compare the urls in the list to users input

i thought i will just split the string('.')

so options are 
for prefix:

```
www.example
```

or just

```
example
```

for the sufix

```
example.com \ biz \net \info ->  (2 parts)
example.co.uk \org.uk (3 parts)
```

so theres lots of options

could be a prefix with aray has 2 elements

```
www.example
```

and sufix with 3 example.co.uk

it is complicated to check it this way,

did i choose the wrong path with comparisson techniq to split the urls by Dots?

i will just show you how i have started and i stopped as soon as i noticed it is too much

this is stil not covering all options and **its already too complicated**

```
if (ListArr[0] != "www")
{ // it means no www so

      compare userArr[0] to ListArr[0] // to check domainMatch

      // and for suffix of domain 
      var DDLValueArr = DDLValue.split('.');
      if(DDLValueArr.length > 1) means it is co.uk or org.uk etc'
      {
             compare DDLValueArr[0] to ListArr[1]   
      }
}

else 
compare userArr[0] to ListArr[1] cause the url in the List starts with "www"
```

what is a good approach to compare users input to the url list ?

Comment: What do you mean compare? Are you trying to see if the user has selected a URI that already exists in the list?

Comment: @keyboardP
yes exactly .

Comment: Are you considering `www.example.com` to be the same as `example.com`? If so, you can just ignore the `www` each time.

Comment: sorry, i forgot it could be maybe that domain will have `http://sub.domainName....` also `httpS://sub.domainName....` etc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) to create the uri, for example:

```
List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>(){ 
   new Uri("http://www.example1.com"), 
   new Uri("https://www.example2.biz"), 
   new Uri("http://www.example3.co.uk")
};

string input = "www.example2.biz";
Uri newUri = new UriBuilder(input).Uri;
if (uris.Any(u=> u.Host == newUri.Host))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already in the list");
}
```

Note that if uri does not specify a scheme, the `UriBuilder` defaults to "http:".

Comment: The AbsolutePath is just the value after the TLD though, right? wouldn't it just be "/" for all of those?

Comment: @Gray: You are right, changed it to co compare the `Host`. If he wants to include the port he has to use `Authoprity`.

Comment: cheers !! this looks Great . i should actually have looked for that kind of class if exists .. but still a full implementation of the test is better then anything else !

Comment: Just to be clear, Host is just "www.example3.co.uk" and "www.example1.com". So, "subdomain.example.com" will be different from "www.example.com". It works for the protocol though "http/https/ftp/etc".

Comment: @Gray forgot to thank you yesterday for your help here ! thanks mate